# entity framework does not map more than one list in model C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have a class "Project" that hat two lists one for "Employee" and one for "tool", when i build my project with only one of the lists the database updates with corrrect relation, if add the second list to the class entity framework can not figureout how to create the relation.

```
 public class Project
{        
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> RequiredEmployees {get;set;}
    public List<Tools> RequiredTools {get;set;}
}

Public class Tool
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
}
```

I get the error "There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table"
i hve tryed to map in ModelBuilder without success

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
    .HasRequired<Project>(s => s.Project)
    .WithMany(g => g.Employee)
    .HasForeignKey<Guid>(s => s.ProjectId);
```

any ideas ?

Comment: You can add `KeyAttribute` in primary key field: `[Key] public Guid Id { get; set; }` and run `Update-Database` afterwards.

Comment: Post the `Tools` class. EF has trouble finding the Key in there.  And if possible, rename it to `Tool`.

Comment: Also, it would be `.WithMany(g => g.RequiredEmployees)`

Comment: I have added simplifyed "tool" class, and i have added the [Key] on id and it still does not work

Comment: "does not work" is never very clear or helpful. Post the exact error message and the _exact_ lines involved.

Comment: Here is the eroor in package console when i try to update database:  "There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.Project' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_dbo.Tools_dbo.Tools_ToolsId'.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors."

Comment: The Required part may be upsetting the conventions. Fix the WithMany(...) for both dependent tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have maneuvered yourself in several problems. The reported error is about the primary key. Furthermore you have problems specifying the one-to-many relations.

**One-To-Many relations**

Entity framework is easy if you follow the [code first conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx) For every deviation you need to tell entity framework about your deviations.

You planned to design a one-to-many between a `Project` and `Tool`: every `Project` has zero or more `Tools`, every `Tool` belongs to exactly one `Project`

If you follow the convention for [one-to-many](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx), you don't have to inform entity framework about this relation; entity framework will detect the relation by convention:

- Use an ICollection instead of a List, after all, what would `RequiredTools[4]` mean?
- Make the ICollection virtual. As long as your Project is a query, it is not a real ICollection, it only contains a class that can produce an ICollection.

Consider using the proper naming conventions.:

```
class Project
{        
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    // a project has zero or more Employees:
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees {get;set;}
    // a project has zero or more Tools
    public virtual ICollectioin<Tool> Tools {get;set;}
}
```

Every Tool belongs to exactly one Project, using foreign key:

```
class Tool
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid ProjectId {get; set;}
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

Similarly: Every Employee belongs to one Project

```
class Employee
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid ProjectId {get; set;}
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

Or use [many-to-many](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) if an Employee can participate in several Projects:

```
class Employee
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // an Employee works in zero or more Projects
    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

And your Dbcontext:

```
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Project> Projects {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Tool> Tools {get; set;}
}
```

This would be enough for entity framework to detect your relations and table names. I'd advice you to reconsider your decision to deviate from the code-first conventions.

However, if you really need to deviate your names you'll have to tell entity framework about your relations and table names:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    // a Project has zero or more Tools via property RequiredTools and table TableName:
    var entityProject = modelBuilder.Entity<Project>();
    entityProject.ToTable(... /* table name */);
    // a project has zero or more tools via property RequiredTools
    // every tool belongs to one required Project 
    // using foreign key ProjectId
    entityproject.HasMany(project => project.RequiredTools)
        .WithRequired(tool => tool.Project)
        .HasFreignKey(tool => tool.ProjectId);
}
```

**Primary Keys**

You chose not to use the conventional type for your primary Keys. The problem is that entity framework does not know how to fill your Id. You'll have to tell entity framework that you'll fill the values for the primary keys.

This is done by overriding [DbContext.SaveChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges(v=vs.113).aspx)

There are also two SaveChangesAsync; we will override them to. Both procedures will call the same function that will generate your Id:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    GenerateIds();
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
{
    GenerateIds();
    return base.SaveChangesAsync();
}
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        this.GenerateIds();
        return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
```

Function `GenerateIds` will get all items that need an Id and give it an Id. The objects that need an Id are all objects with state Added.

However, the object in the DbContext that remembered all changes that need to be saved, only knows that these objects are DbEntityEntries. It does not know which property in your DbEntityEntry represents the primary key.

You could solve this using KeyAttribute. Get the added entry, ask for its type, ask the type for the property that has the KeyAttribute and set the value of this property.

This method has several disadvantages. Reflection is a fairly slow process, it depends on you giving all classes that need a GUID to add the KeyAttribute, it is not type safe, and you will only detect that your made mistakes at run-time.

It is much better to define that all your entity classes should implement an interface that defines the primary key:

```
public interface IPrimaryKey
{
     GUID Id {get; set;}
}

class Tool : IPrimaryKey {...}
class Project : IPrimaryKey {...}
```

If you forgot to implement your Id, your compiler will warn you. GenerateIds is now fairly simple:

```
private void GenerateIds()
{
    foreach (DbEntityEntry addedEntry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
       .Where(entry => entry.State == EntityState.Added))
    {
        // every entry implements IPrimaryKey. Fill the Id           
        (IPrimaryKey)entry.Id = this.CreateId
    }
}

private GUID CreateId()
{
    return Guid.NewGuid(); // or use your own Guid creator
}
```

Comment: Great answer! What do you mean with "You chose not to use the conventional type for your primary Keys"? You mean that the OP used `Guid` instead of `int`? Can't we accomplish the same decorating the PK with [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]?

Comment: No, I didn't mean that. I meant the a Person doesn't have `Id` or `PersonId` as primary key, and an Order does not have `Id` or `OrderId` as primary Key. If you'd use one of these identifiers Entity Framework would assume this would be the primary key. If you choose to use a different identifier you'll have t.o tell entity framework the name of your primary key

Answer (score 0):

To be sure we would need to see your `Tools` class, but I think that the problem is that Entity Framework can't find a property to use as Primary Key in it.

The Entity Framework convention establishes that the Primary Key of a class is named `Id` or `<ClassName>Id` (in this case `ToolsId`). If you want a property with a name different from this ones to be the PK, you have to specify it explicitly, with the [`[Key]` attribute](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/key-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) or with the [Fluent API](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/haskey-method).

Comment: i have added         [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; } and it does not work